# CSS border radius rounds corners but not background

Tags: css, rounded-corners

I'm using a 15px rounded border on a div, and the border itself is rounded on the outside but on the inside (where border meets background) it's still a square corner.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BQT5F/1/

I thought `background-clip` would help out here but it doesn't. This should be possible, right?

(Also, I know it's not IE compatible, I'm just aiming for chrome and FF for the moment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a rounded inner border, the border radius must be greater than the border thickness. For example:

border-radius: 30px;
border-width: 15px;

Comment: Wow, that actually makes perfect sense. Thanks.